# How to make changes in xsl to get distinct values in xsl

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Am getting duplicates in the list, SO i wanted to make distinct .

```
Workflow Type (
    <xsl:for-each select="//Bonaire/RBS/WorkflowTypeList">
    <xsl:if test="@BSSLOOKUPTYPEID=//Bonaire/Request/@TYPE_BSSLOOKUPTYPEID">
    <xsl:value-of select="@TYPENAME"/>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
 )
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please post an example of the input and the expected output - see: [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

That can be done in a one-liner using `distinct-values()` and predicate expression (`[...]`) :

```
<xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(//Bonaire/RBS/WorkflowTypeList[@BSSLOOKUPTYPEID=//Bonaire/Request/@TYPE_BSSLOOKUPTYPEID]/@TYPENAME)">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```